# my esp8266 using cached how to fix

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

```
UID tag : 04 7F C7 BA 20 4B 80
Message : 04 7F C7 BA 20 4B 80TCP connection ready
Sending..
Packet sent

+IPD,210:HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.14.0
Date: Tue, 05 Jun 2018 11:51:29 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Acc-Exp: 600
X-Proxy-Cache: HIT localarra.com

0
```

above is code i am able to call my api but only once how i disable cache in esp8266 arduino project. my all code work properly just esp8266 every time show response from cache i tried with postman it called every time but not with esp8266 please comment if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

Those are headers returned by the web server you're accessing.

The cache isn't in the ESP8266, it's in the web server. The web site is being served through a proxy server which caches pages - this is usually done to help performance, like in a Content Distribution Network.

It's possible that if you append a URL query parameter that the proxy server will serve you a fresh copy of the page rather than a cached copy.

You didn't share the URL you're accessing, so suppose it's

`http://www.example.com/page`

In that case,

`http://www.example.com/something?foo=1`

might cause the proxy to bypass the cache.

If that doesn't work then you're probably not going bypass the server's cache.

However - the web site operator likely has good reason for using a cache - it's not something you should need to bypass.